# Suppose $E$ is the quotient field of $D$ then find the relation between $D[x]$ and $E[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $D$ be an integral domain, then $D[x]$ is an  integral domain and find its quotient field. Suppose $E$ is the quotient field of $D$. Then find the relation between $D[x]$ and $E[x]$.

I have proved the fact $D[x]$ is an  integral domain and got its quotient field.

But what will be the relation between $D[x]$ and $E[x]$ and how to prove it?

Comment: There is an inclusion $i:D[X]\rightarrow E[X]$. Further relations? I suppose it may be useful to look at $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ but am not sure what else may be reasonable. Just comments

Answer (score 1):

The ring $E[x]$ can be considered as an overring of $D[x]$, hence also of $D$; then is the ring of quotients of $D[x]$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $D\setminus\{0\}$ (or of the multiplicative set of nonzero noninvertible elements of $D$, if one wants the minimal set).

I don't think much more than this can be said.

Answer (score -1):

$D[x]\subset E[x]$

Proof:Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n\in D[x]$

then $a_i\in D\subset E$ and hence $f(x)\in E[x]$

Comment: why down vote?Any answer